# How to split this string in Dart? /data/data/com.example.trail/cache/IMG_1645484057312.png

Tags: dart

I need to get the name of an image path, which is a String. How could i say programmatically in dart "when you find the first / from the right hand side split it, then give it to me"?

**the string which i need to split is:**

'/data/data/com.example.trail/cache/IMG_1645484057312.png'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split` like the @scott-deagan answer for it. But if you intend to support cross-platform path manipulation, you need to use [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path) package.

Example:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

void main() {
  var filepath = '/data/data/com.example.trail/cache/IMG_1645484057312.png';
  
  print(p.basename(filepath));
  print(p.basenameWithoutExtension(filepath));
  
}
```

result:

```
IMG_1645484057312.png
IMG_1645484057312
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  var someFile = '/data/data/com.example.trail/cache/IMG_1645484057312.png';
  var fname = someFile.split('/').last;
  var path = someFile.replaceAll("/$fname", '');
  print(fname);
  print(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I recommend you to test

First, do the split on the original string by "/" splitter, then extract the last member of the list created by the splitter to get the name of the png file.

Second, for extracting the remaining string (i.e. the file path), use the substring method of the class string. just by subtracting the original string length from the last_member length in the previous portion, you are able to get the file path string.

Hope to be useful
Bests

```
void main() {
  String a = '/data/data/com.example.trail/cache/IMG_1645484057312.png';
  var splited_a = a.split('/');
  var last_image_index = splited_a.last;
  String remaining_string = a.substring(0, a.length - last_image_index.length);
  print(remaining_string);
  print(last_image_index);
}
```

result:

[the result of path and file extraction from a string in dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNM20.png)